# GGplot geom_bar stack items with even spacing

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I was wondering if anyone has a solution for me as I would like to visualize a stacked bar chart that kinda looks like this:
[image]

This was made with a little data.table and the ggplot code below

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

dt <- data.table(id = seq(15), pvalue = c(0.0323616533686601, 0.00405825892193357, 0.00406609088355357, 0.00252697950679603, 0.00277696431629866, 0.0212521760053885, 0.0315721033650767, 0.00716594255390525, 0.00829537987151543, 0.0163753389504665, 0.0328650069220695, 0.0146991756928858, 0.0178425139730873, 0.00345987886149332, 0.0499748920124661))

ggplot(dt, aes(1, id, fill = pvalue)) + geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```

But I'm looking for a slight modification. The data has an id column ranging from 1 to 15, this causes every item to have the corresponding size. But I would like to have them the same height/size.

This can be achieved with this bit of code:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(id, fill = pvalue)) + geom_bar(stat = 'count') + coord_flip()
```

But when I run this bit, I loose the ability to color them correctly (with scale_fill_gradient2)
[image]

Let me know if you find a nice solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think adding `group=` is what you are after:

```
ggplot(dt, aes(y=id, fill = pvalue, group=id)) + 
    geom_bar()
```

And if you define `y=` you don't need to `coord_flip()`

ps, `geom_col()` is the same as `geom_bar(stat = 'identity')`

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I'm looking for, do you by any chance also have a solution to remove the bits of whitespace between the bars?

Comment: Add `geom_bar(width = 1) ` to remove whitespace.